# How do i run a php script every 2 hour on amazon ec2 cloud?

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, cron

I am trying to run a php script every hour on amazon ec2 cloud but not able to run it.
I am using it

```
MAILTO="email@something.com"
* */2 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/sports/webservices/cron-job.php
```

I have also mentioned my email in `MAILTO`. But not receiving any email and it is not updating the database.

When i changed (removed `/usr/bin/php`) it with this

```
MAILTO="email@something.com"
* */2 * * * /var/www/html/sports/webservices/cron-job.php
```

then I received an email with this error message.

```
/var/www/html/sports/webservices/cron-job.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/var/www/html/sports/webservices/cron-job.php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `0'
/var/www/html/sports/webservices/cron-job.php: line 2: `error_reporting(0);'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that a cronjob is normally executes as sh script. So you need to let the php script been executed by the php interpreter. Try to use:

```
* */2 * * * /bin/php5 /var/www/html/sports/webservices/cron-job.php
```

Please note that the php binary can also be `php` in the directory `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: it says that `/bin/sh: /bin/php5: No such file or directory`. I am also using this: `* */2 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/sports/webservices/cron-job.php but nothing happening.

Comment: Try /usr/bin/php instat of /bin/php5